# Calculating the Jacobian Matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working with the system:

$$ u' = v $$ 
$$ v' = -w^{2}sin(3\pi+u)-cv $$

where $c$ and $w$ are positive constants.

I'm computing the Jacobian matrix:

$$J=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        F_u & F_v \\
        G_u & G_v \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ J=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -w^2cos(3\pi+u) & -c \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is this correct? I think I am doing something wrong with calculating the derivative of $-w^{2}sin(3\pi+u)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you get that $G_v$?

The rest looks good assuming $\omega$ is a constant.

Comment: Shoot -- it should be $-c$.

Comment: That looks better!

Comment: Great feedback, and a $\checkmark$ too! +1